# Python using tkcalendar with if-statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, tkinter, tkcalendar

Im trying to make if-statements with tkcalendar but dont know why it is not working.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *
import datetime

root = Tk()
root.title('Hi')
root.geometry('500x400')

cal = Calendar(root, date_pattern="d/m/y", year = 2020, month = 11, day = 1)
cal.pack(pady=20)

def grab_date():
    my_label.config(text = cal.get_date())
    d = cal.get_date()
    print(d)
    if datetime.datetime.strptime('01/11/2020', "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y") 
    <=d<=datetime.datetime.strptime('01/1/2021', "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y"):
        print('ok')

my_button = Button(root, text = 'Get date', command = grab_date)
my_button.pack()

my_label = Label(root, text = ' ')
my_label.pack(pady = 20)

root.mainloop()
```

It does not print 'ok' when I press the button between the dates. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem and how the if-statements are done when using tkcalendar? I want to then to add more conditions of when other dates are pressed print something else.

Comment: what exactly you wanna check in if statement?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani look if I press  on the button between '01/11/2020' and '01/1/2021' I want the program to print: ok

Comment: Does `cal.get_date()` return a datetime object or do you need to convert it first?

Comment: @scotty3785 it returns a datetime object with format: day/month/year

Comment: @Carl-ErikPettersson Are you sure? The tkcalendar documentation suggests that `get_date` returns a string. https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Calendar.html#tkcalendar.Calendar.get_date

Comment: why are you `strptime` & `strftime` ??

Comment: Good shout @HarshaBiyani, Carl-Erik Pettersson should be comparing datetime objects rather than strings so converting the string to a datetime and then back to a string again makes no sense.

Comment: @scotty3785 can you show me an example of how? I have been trying to search but cant find how

Comment: @HarshaBiyani because I want to remove hours:minutes:seconds

Comment: @scotty3785 I understand exactly what you mean. But unfortunately I dont know how to do it when using tkcalendar

Comment: @Carl-ErikPettersson See my answer. I don't have tkcalendar installed but this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the below example.

```
import datetime



def betweenDates(date,start,end):
    return (date>start) and (date<end)

start = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/11/2020', "%d/%m/%Y").date()
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/1/2021', "%d/%m/%Y").date()

today = datetime.datetime.now().date()

if betweenDates(today,start,end):
    print("Ok")
```

This will compare today's date to see if it is between two specified dates using a function (makes the if statement line shorter and the comparison reusable).

To do this with tkcalendar you need to convert the date from it to a datetime object (or since you want to remove the time, a datetime.date object)

Since tkcalendar returns a string you need to use strptime to parse it. Might look like this

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(cal.get_date(),"%d/%m/%Y").date()
```

Hope that helps you to get your code working

Edit: Your function may look like this. Untested however due to lack of tkcalendar installed

```
def grab_date():
    my_label.config(text = cal.get_date())
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(cal.get_date(),"%d/%m/%Y").date()
    print(d)
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/11/2020', "%d/%m/%Y").date()
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/1/2021', "%d/%m/%Y").date()
    if betweenDates(d,start,end):
        print('ok')
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I will try this out! Do you mean that I should put:         
if betweenDates(d,start,end):
    print("Ok")                                                                                        where d = datetime.datetime.strptime(cal.get_date(),"%d/%m/%Y").date()

Comment: Or should I also do something with start, end?

Comment: @Carl-ErikPettersson No. I've edited my question to show how it might look. You could also consider changing `betweenDates` to do the conversion from string to datetime.date() objects

Comment: You are right it said:TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date. I should do some changes in the betweenDates-function. I returned like this: return (date.datetime.date()>start.datetime.date()) and (date.datetime.date()<=end.datetime.date()), but it wasnt right. Do you know what it can be?

Comment: My mistake. Add `.date()` to the end of the line that starts with `d =`. Then all `d`, `start` and `end` will all be `datetime.date` objects and comparable